# Avoid textField get focus - Android

Tags: android, appcelerator, textfield, appcelerator-titanium

Is there a way to avoid the textField get the focus when the windows load ?
i have this in my tiapp.xml

```
 <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomActionBar"/>
        <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="23"
            android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

the android:windowSoftInputMode should do the work, but nothings happend.
thanks in advance..

Comment: you need to do this with respect to screens. @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);}

Comment: thanks @Stallion but i think your solution is for native android development.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this module:

https://github.com/mpociot/TiAndroidAutofocus

......................................................

Comment: Welll i try it but just work the first time, when i open the window for the second time, the app crash.

Comment: What is causing the crash? Do you have some crash logs from LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` will do the trick.

Just define your Activity in manifest file like this.

```
<activity
        android:name="packagename.classname"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to address this behavior is by adding the following layout to your XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autotext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/autotext"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/autotext"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

By dooing that your focus will be moved to an invisible component. You can create a layout and include it in your main XML make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks @edgar but i think your answer is for native development.